# for loop won't begin at i = 0

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
//write_db_iec(writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer()[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer().size(); i++) {
     write_db_iec(writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer()[i]);
  }
```

Is there any possibilities, that the for loop start directly with i = 1?
The first element ( i = 0 ) is accessible and contains element.

[Edited] : I want that the loop starts from i = 0. But it fails.

Below is the function write_db_iec:

```
void write_db_iec(db_iec db_timer) {
    writer_file.open(writer_file_location, std::ios::app);
    if (writer_file.is_open()) {
        //NOTICE
        std::cout << "Begin writing db timer-\n";

        //COMMENT
        writer_file << "//DATA BLOCK FOR TIMER -\n";
        writer_file << "//FOR " << db_timer.get_db_iec_timer().get_name() << "\n";

        //HEADER
        writer_file << "DATA_BLOCK " << db_timer.get_db_name() << "\n"
            << "{ S7_Optimized_Access := 'FALSE'}\n"
            << "NAME : " << db_timer.get_db_iec_timer().get_type() << "\n"
            << "VERSION : 0.1\n";

        //RELATED FB
        writer_file << "BEGIN\n"
            << "END_DATA_BLOCK\n\n\n";

        //CLOSE FILE
        writer_file.close();
    }
    else {
        writer_status = false;
        std::cout << "Error on writing timer DB\n";
        std::cout << "Timer DB Name : " << db_timer.get_db_iec_timer().get_name() << "\n";

    }


}
```

[ADDED] :
The class ob1 :

```
class ob1 {
private:
std::vector<std::string> ob1_var_temp;
std::vector<fb> ob1_fb;
std::vector<db> ob1_db;
std::vector<db_iec> ob1_db_timer;

//load var temp for ob1, should be called before writer
void load_var_temp() {
    //not important
}

public:
ob1() { load_var_temp(); }
ob1(fb fb1) {
    ob1_fb.push_back(fb1);
    load_var_temp();

}

std::vector<fb> &get_vector_fb() {
    return ob1_fb;
}

std::vector<db> &get_vector_db() {
    return ob1_db;
}

std::vector<db_iec> &get_vector_db_timer() {
    return ob1_db_timer;
}

std::vector<std::string> &get_vector_var_temp() {
    return ob1_var_temp;
}




//to generate db, should be called before writer
void generate_db(std::vector<fb> functionblock) {
    if (functionblock.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < functionblock.size(); i++) {
            ob1_db.push_back(functionblock[i]);

        }
    }
}

//overloaded function from generate db
void generate_db() {
    std::vector<fb> functionblock = ob1_fb;
    if (functionblock.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < functionblock.size(); i++) {
            ob1_db.push_back(functionblock[i]);

        }
    }
}

//to generate db timer, should be called before writer
void generate_db_timer(std::vector<fb> functionblock) {
    for (int i = 0; i < functionblock.size(); i++) {
        if (functionblock[i].get_timer().size() > 0) {
            ob1_db_timer.push_back(functionblock[i].get_timer()[i]);

        }
    }
}

//to generate db timer, should be called before writer, overloaded function
void generate_db_timer() {
    std::vector<fb> functionblock = ob1_fb;
    for (int i = 0; i < functionblock.size(); i++) {
        if (functionblock[i].get_timer().size() > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < functionblock[i].get_timer().size(); j++) {
                ob1_db_timer.push_back(functionblock[i].get_timer()[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

//to add fb into ob1
void add_fb(fb functionblock) {
    ob1_fb.push_back(functionblock);
}

};
```

It has vector of class db_iec. And here it is the class db_iec :

```
// data block for iec timer
class db_iec {
private:
timer db_iec_timer;
std::string db_name;

public:
db_iec() {}
db_iec(timer iec_timer) : db_iec_timer{ iec_timer } {}

std::string &get_db_name() {
    return db_name;
}

timer &get_db_iec_timer() {
    return db_iec_timer;
}
};
```

And the last, where I declare my function and call it in a for loop

```
void analyse_ob1() {

    writer_file.open(writer_file_location);
    if (writer_file.is_open()) {
        writer_file << "///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n";
        writer_file << "//This is an automatically generated code\n";
        time_t theTime = time(NULL);
        struct tm *aTime = localtime(&theTime);

        int day = aTime->tm_mday;
        int month = aTime->tm_mon + 1; // Month is 0 - 11, add 1 to get a jan-dec 1-12 concept
        int year = aTime->tm_year + 1900;
        int second = aTime->tm_sec;
        int minute = aTime->tm_min;
        int hour = aTime->tm_hour;
        writer_file << "//Date : " << day << "." << month << "." << year << "\n";
        writer_file << "//Time : " << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second << "\n";
        writer_file << "///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n\n";



    }


    //write_db_iec(writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer()[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer().size(); i++) {
        //writer_file.open(writer_file_location, std::ios::app);
        //writer_file << "DB_Number : " << i << "\n";

        write_db_iec(writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer()[i]);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < writer_ob1.get_vector_fb().size(); i++) {
            write_fb(writer_ob1.get_vector_fb()[i]);
            write_db(writer_ob1.get_vector_db()[i]);
    }



    write_ob1();

}


};
```

[SOLVED] : I have to close the file first (writer_file.close()) before I call the function write_db_iec(). Thank you for all of your answer.

Comment: What does `writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer()` do? And haveyou tried stepping through the code in a debugger? Including stepping into all the functions? Lastly, and most importantly, *why* do you think the loop doesn't start with `i` equal to `0`? What is the problem you're having? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes I have tried it. In debugger it shows me that the function write_db_iec has been called for the first element ( i = 0), but I don't see any output written in my file. The  writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer() returns a vector of db_iec

Comment: How many elements are in the vector? Are you *sure* it's enough to access `[i]`?

Comment: The vector has 4 Elements. All elements can be accessed.

Comment: OK, cool. What makes you think `i` is `1` when it enters the loop?

Comment: Because the first element (i = 0) is not written in my writer_file. But if i put the first line out of comment ( where I call the first element before the for loop ), I get the first element written on my file

Comment: But all the other elements are? How many times does `Begin writing db timer-` show in std out?

Comment: Are you able to show us code that reproduces the problem? As you try to narrow it down to a minimal example you might spot it yourself.

Comment: If you step through the loop and see that `write_db_iec` is called, but it doesn't write anything to your file. Then the problem is not with the loop but with the `write_db_iec` function, or any function that it calls. You have to step *into* that function and make sure int work as it should.

Comment: @doctorlove for vector with 4 Elements. It shows 4 times in std::cout

Comment: So it goes round the loop four times, but only write three records to the file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah but the problem is that it works for element 2-4 ( i = 1 until i = 3). And it also works if try to call the function with the parameter of the first element ( i = 0 ).

Comment: @doctorlove yes it only writes three records to the file

Comment: We need a reproducible example. I suggest you add `writer_file_location` to the output debug

Comment: @doctorlove I don't really understand what you mean. Should I put writer_file_location to std::cout ?

Comment: I can't see what it is from the code you've posted. Try `std::cout << "Begin writing db timer-" << writer_file_location << '\n';` just in case something else (we can't see from here) is changing that.

Comment: It mentions the same file location. @doctorlove

Comment: Then it's time to do something you should have done from the beginning, to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Including (but not limited to) showing what `writer_ob1` is and the definition of its class, and most importantly the `get_vector_db_timer` implementation.

Comment: Judging by the code you show it should work. The only things it could be is either if you have a buffer overflow somewhere and overwrite memory  belonging to `writer_ob1`, or that the `writer_ob1` object isn't constructed and initialized properly, or is a reference to a non-existing object. In short, you have some *undefined behavior* somewhere manifesting as a problem here.

Comment: I found the problem. I have to close the file before open it again. I don't know if it should be like that, because if it's open then you can write in the file. But it works for me after I close the file and in the function write_db_iec I open the file again.  Thank you once again @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: To understand why this is happening, if you read e.g. [this `std::ofstream::open` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) you see that it calls [`std::filebuf::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) which will return a null pointer if the file is already open, and a null pointer return indicates a failure so the file will not be in the correct state. Check if it is open *before* trying to (re)open it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the for loop, that's for sure. Unless `writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer().size() == 0` , the loop body will be executed with `i = 0`. Otherwise the loop body won't be executed at all.

Make sure that the vector returned from `writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer()` indeed contains the elements you're expecting.

Comment: No it has 4 elements

Comment: @ptd And it _should_ contain 4 elements and not 5?

Comment: it should contain 4 elements. Becaus of the input that I have given to the programm, it has 4 Elements, and in debugger mode it has also 4 Elements. So with the count of element it has no problem.

Comment: @ptd next thing to do is to check whether the element at 0 really contains the data you're expecting

Comment: Yes it does. The line just before the loop that I put in comment, it works.

Comment: Okay, then the only difference is that `writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer().size()` is called before `write_db_iec`. Is that an `std::vector`? What does `get_vector_db_timer()` do exactly?

Comment: Exactly it is. It just return a vector of <db_iec>. That is a class.

Comment: And that vector is not mutated elsewhere? Also, please try the range-based for loop: `for (db_timer& timer : writer_ob1.get_vector_db_timer()) { .. }`

Comment: It didn't change the behavior. Element 2-4 got printed but not the first one

Comment: Maybe `writer_file.is_open()` returns `false` for the first time. Have you cheked that?

Comment: I have checked it.  No it returns true